# ¿Cómo puedo calcular la nota media de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando calcular la media de los valores que hay en un arreglo, pero no me sale nada.

```js
function medias() {
  let notas = ['3', '6', '8', '2']

  let media = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < notas; i++) {
    media += notas[i];
  }
  console.log(media / notas.length);

}

medias();
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Acabo de actualizarlo, se he me ha escapado.

Comment: Aún así no me calcula la medía del arreglo

Comment: Me ha servido tu respuesta y la de abajo, que despiste gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que considerar varias cosas en tu función.

Lo primero es que tu arreglo de debe contener datos numéricos para que al ser sumados no los concatene y te dé el resultado de la suma:

```js
let notas = [3, 6, 8, 2];
```

Sin las comillas entre los números.

Otro detalles es en el ciclo. Debes tener en cuenta que vas contando hasta la longitud de tu arreglo, por lo que falta:

```js
for(let i=0; i < notas.length; i++ )
```

Nota que dentro del ciclo usamos el **.length** para condicionar la salida.

Corregido eso, ya debería devolverte el arreglo invocando el método como mencionan en los comentarios.

Al final te quedaría:

```js
function medias() {
  let notas = [3, 6, 8, 2]

  var media = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
    media += notas[i];
  }
  console.log(media / notas.length);
}

medias();
```

Comment: Gracias, ese era el error que no había indicado que contase la cantidad en el bucle, y ya corregí el arreglo.